# Existe alguma estratégia para um banco de dados "desfazível"?

Tags: banco-de-dados, histórico

Já vi em alguns sites (como até mesmo o Stack Exchange) uma possibilidade de "desfazer" uma ação no banco de dados (como nas edições de perguntas / respostas).

Estive pensando em algumas soluções possíveis, mas estou com medo de estar reinventando a roda. Queria saber se essa estratégia já existe, padrão ou não, e se é eficiente. Senão, gostaria de saber se há alguma alternativa.

(Estou aceitando respostas de bancos de dados relacionais **e** não-relacionais, mas preferiria uma resposta válida para ambos)

Comment: Só para esclarecer, você não está falando de `ROLLBACK` de transações, né? Na SE, por exemplo, o que acontece é que nada é excluído do banco, somente é marcado como excluído. A última revisão de um post é a que vale, mas todas as anteriores são possíveis, e mantidas numa tabela específica. Essa é uma das estratégias possíveis.

Comment: @bfavaretto Não estou falando de `Rollback`s não, é do segundo caso mesmo. Eu tive essa ideia mas não sei qual o melhor jeito de implementá-la, e estava com medo de algo mais fácil de já existir e eu estar querendo reinventar a roda.

Comment: Eu acredito que a melhor solução vá sempre depender da estrutura do seu banco. Mas como exemplo, algumas opções extremas seriam a) ter um flag de exclusão (+ data e usuário) em cada tabela; b) manter um espelho de cada tabela para o histórico de dados; c) manter uma tabela única de log para o banco todo, com os dados serializados de alguma maneira.

Comment: @bfavaretto Eu já tinha pensado nas opções (a) e (c). Espero que alguém me aponte para qual cenário cada uma é melhor -- ou se tem uma que se sobressai sobre as outras.

Comment: Eu tenho experiência com a opção (a), mas agora estou cansado demais para relatar os prós e contras numa resposta decente. Pretendo fazer isso com calma outra hora, ok?

Comment: @bfavaretto Sem problemas, estou numa viagem do trabalho e só posso usar o computador de madrugada. A pergunta foi mais uma curiosidade do que uma necessidade, então não há necessidade pra pressa

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### O que é a operação desfazer?

O conceito de desfazer, possui sua melhor descrição nos sistemas de
versionamento de arquivos. Das variantes de comportamento entre os diferentes
sistemas de versionamento, vou destacar alguns parâmetros que considero
importantes, na construção de algo parecido.

Esses sistemas armazenam todas as alterações feitas nos arquivos (registros)
para sempre, **na integra, ou na forma de diff em relação à versão anterior**.
Isso quer dizer que é possível reconstruir qualquer um dos arquivos em
qualquer ponto do tempo, desde que exista um registro de cada alteração feita.

Cada registro, possui uma **indicação exata de qual é a versão anterior**
dele, sendo que um registro pode ter no máximo uma base. Isso pode ser feito
na forma de um apontamento, ou seja, uma referência ao registro anterior.
Assim sendo, dois registros podem ter como base o mesmo registro anterior.

Note que isso permite construir uma árvore de alterações.
Desfazer (ou até mesmo refazer), significa meramente alterar o HEAD de lugar,
seja isso feito na forma de uma **flag, ou de um apontamento**.
O HEAD é uma indicação de qual dentre todos os registros existentes na árvore,
é a versão corrente.

Finalmente, temos de considerar a unidade de trabalho para a ação de desfazer.
Nos sistemas de versionamento, é possível **desfazer alterações menores do que a
unidade de trabalho**, que seria um commit. Entretanto, isso não é algo de
extrema necessidade e você poderia simplesmente **usar unidades de trabalho
menores**, e permitir desfazer apenas na integra, mas não parcialmente.

### Decidindo quais recursos devo implementar

**Armazenar na integra, ou apenas os diffs**

- **Armazenar na integra:** armazenar tudo na integra torna tudo mais símples.
  Não é necessário fazer diff dos registros, o que é uma tarefa complexa.
  Para recuperar um registro em qualquer ponto,
  não é necessário reconstruir desde o início, ou de um snapshot anterior.
- **Armazenar diffs:** armazenar diffs pode ter vantagens, pois diffs são mais
  compactos, e portanto requerem menos espaço de armazenamento.

**Como saber qual é a versão anterior**

- **Apontamento para o anterior:** eu recomendo um apontamento para o registro
  anterior. Eu acho que é dessa forma que a maioria dos programadores esperaria
  que fosse feito, e portanto é a que possui menor barreira de entrada para
  outros programadores.

**Implementando um indicador de HEAD**

- **Braches:** Existem sistemas de versionamento de arquivos que possuem
  vários braches de desenvolvimento, ou seja, várias visões do que é a versão
  corrente. Isso requer que exista algo no
  sistema que represente um brach, e é esse objeto que irá dizer qual o seu HEAD.
- **Sem branches:** Essa é a mais símples. Não existem várias visões do
  conteúdo. Apenas um branch com apenas um HEAD. Ainda assim poderia existir
  um registro específico para o branch no banco de dados, que aponte para o HEAD,
  isso torna o sistema flexível e o permite se desenvolver para outros caminho,
  ou então usar uma flag em um campo de um dos elementos da árvore... o que além
  de inflexível, eu acho que seria mais complicado, principalmente para garantir
  que só existe um registro da árvore que possui a flag ligada.

**Sobre a unidade de trabalho**

A unidade de trabalho é cada nó da árvore. Existem duas formas de desfazer,
uma que permite desfazer alterações menores que a unidade de trabalho, e outra
que permite desfazer apenas unidades de trabalho inteiras.

- **Desfazer unidades inteiras:** essa é a forma mais fácil de implementar.
  Requer apenas que o apontamento do HEAD seja alterado. Para permitir ações de
  desfazer mais granulares, é possível utilizar unidades de trabalho menores.
  Por exemplo, se o sistema é composto de POSTS atualizados por vários usuários,
  como o StackOverflow, a unidade de trabalho pode ser uma postagem inteira, o que é o
  caso, ou então se fosse necessário desfazer apenas tags independentes do
  conteúdo, poderiam haver duas árvores de alterações: uma para conteúdo e outra
  para tags, ou seja, dois sistemas de desfazer mais granulares.
- **Desfazer unidades parcialmente:** essa forma de desfazer, não pode ser
  chamada bem assim, pois ela requer um MERGE e portanto um novo registro de
  alteração. Recorrendo ao exemplo anterior, em que se deseja desfazer conteúdo
  e tags de uma postagem de forma independente, se a unidade de trabalho fosse
  a postagem, então para desfazer apenas tags até um ponto passado `P0`,
  teria de se criar um novo objeto de postagem `P2`,
  copiando as tags do ponto desejado `P0`, e indicando que a
  nova postagem `P2` é um MERGE entre o anterior `P1` e o ponto `P0`:

  ```
  Resumindo: P2 => P0 + P1 (MERGE)
  ```

  Dito isso, dá para ver que um sistema desses é bem mais difícil de se implementar.

Comment: +1 e aguardo a continuação. :D

Comment: Só posso dizer uma coisa: perfeito. Acho que nunca tive uma resposta tão boa quanto essa. Se eu pudesse, daria mais de um upvote. Explicou detalhadamente o que pode ser feito e cada vantagem / desvantagem.

Comment: Uma coisa que eu nunca ouvi de alguém já ter tentado, e que talvez seja possível, é usar um sistemas de versionamento de arquivos como banco de dados. Se isso fosse possível, poderia usar todo o poder, por exemplo do GIT, para manipular informações editadas por uma comunidade.

Comment: Alguém já teve essa ideia: https://speakerdeck.com/bkeepers/git-the-nosql-database